# Python - Sample from 'x' lists with different distribution

Tags: python, numpy, random

In the following code, I've created a list of items and users. I've separated the items to 3 different lists of very popular, popular and regular items.

```
import numpy as np


N_USERS = 20000
N_ITEMS = 1000

items = range(0, N_ITEMS)
users = range(0, N_USERS)

vpop = int(len(items)*0.1)
pop = int(len(items)*0.3)

np.random.shuffle(items)
vpop_items = items[:vpop]
pop_items = items[vpop:pop]
reg_items = items [pop:]
```

I want to sample `X` samples from those lists with different distribution. For example:

```
list_of_items = sample(vpop_items, pop_items, reg_items, p = [0.5, 0.35, 0.15], X)
```

where `X` is the number of samples I want to make, and `P` is the list of distributions corresponding with the lists (`vpop_items`, `pop_items`, `reg_items`).

So in the end I will have `X` "items" in `list_of_items`.

Let's say `X = 100`. I want 100 samples in total, with 0.5 chance from `vpop_items`, 0.35 chance from `pop_items`, and 0.15 chance from `reg_items`. The sampling must be done without replacement, that is, no item can be selected more than once.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to sample from the three lists with the probabilities given by `p`. And you then choose a random item from the respective list? And should chosen items be removed? And finally, have you tried to implement `sample`?

Comment: I want to sample X items. Lets say 100 items. I want to sample 100 items from all the above lists with 0.5 chance from vpop_items. 0.35 chance from pop_items. And 0.15 chance from reg_items

Comment: And have you tried anything yet? pick a random number `p` form 0 to 1, if `p < 0.5` draw from vpop, else if `p < 0.85` draw from pop, else draw from reg. Repeat `X` times.

Comment: I think `X * 0.5` is number of items you need to get from `vpop`, `X * 0.35` from `pop` and `X * 0.15` from `req`.

Comment: Yes I have a really unpythonic and messed up solution where I use a for loop and generate a random num which indicates which list to chose and then just randomly sample item from that list, then I need to remember not to sample the same number again. Its messed up. I hoped for a more elegant solution

Comment: Unless there is a built-in in a library that I'm not aware of I don't see what else you can do..

Comment: @EranMoshe Can you please clearly state what your problem or question is?

Comment: @EranMoshe That info in your first comment belongs in the body of the question itself.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Your suggested algorithm is fast, but not _quite_ what Eran wants to do. But I guess it could be modified to give the desired distribution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a plain Python algorithm that does what you want. It's more efficient than what you're currently doing, but I'm sure there's a smarter way to do it. :)

Let `num` be the total number of samples wanted. We first generate `num` random numbers in the range 0 - 1, and test them against the desired cumulative probabilities, keeping count of how many numbers occur in each probability range. Next, we sample each sequence, using the counts we found in the first step as the sample size. Finally, we shuffle those samples together.

In the code below I've commented out the lines that do the shuffling to make it easier to see what's going on while testing the code.

```
from random import seed, random, sample, shuffle
from itertools import accumulate

def multi_sample(seqs, probs, num):
    ''' Sample from each sequence in list/tuple `seqs` with the corresponding 
        probability in list/tuple `probs`. Return a list containing `num` samples
    '''
    # Compute the cumulative probability
    # This really should raise ValueError if aprobs[-1] != 1.0
    # and we ought to check that len(seqs) == len(probs)...
    aprobs = list(accumulate(probs))

    # Determine how many samples to take from each seq
    counts = [0] * len(seqs)
    for _ in range(num):
        x = random()
        for i, p in enumerate(aprobs):
            if x < p:
                break
        counts[i] += 1

    lst = []
    for seq, count in zip(seqs, counts):
        lst.extend(sample(seq, count))

    #shuffle(lst)
    return lst

# Test

N_ITEMS = 1000
items = list(range(N_ITEMS))
vpop = int(N_ITEMS * 0.1)
pop = int(N_ITEMS * 0.3)

#shuffle(items)
vpop_items = items[:vpop]
pop_items = items[vpop:pop]
reg_items = items[pop:]

all_items = (vpop_items, pop_items, reg_items)

list_of_items = multi_sample(all_items, probs=[0.5, 0.35, 0.15], num=100)
print(list_of_items)

# Verify

#list_of_items.sort()
#print(list_of_items)

# Should be ~50
print(sum(1 for x in list_of_items if x < vpop))
# Should be ~35
print(sum(1 for x in list_of_items if vpop <= x < pop))
```

**typical output**

```
[65, 16, 81, 97, 30, 33, 52, 92, 96, 72, 50, 4, 75, 7, 44, 18, 90, 9, 91, 56, 85, 28, 84, 88, 76, 21, 14, 77, 8, 59, 22, 34, 93, 95, 63, 10, 99, 41, 60, 36, 66, 2, 13, 64, 51, 43, 11, 106, 153, 235, 189, 132, 150, 226, 196, 247, 245, 194, 172, 227, 202, 256, 163, 205, 131, 192, 295, 147, 246, 108, 291, 155, 128, 171, 141, 124, 102, 210, 294, 284, 276, 148, 122, 290, 948, 566, 894, 884, 310, 476, 562, 313, 357, 846, 794, 317, 335, 599, 370, 988]
47
37
```

Be aware that this function can fail: if you call `sample(seq, count)` where `count > len(seq)` it will raise `ValueError: Sample larger than population`. So you need to ensure that `num` is small enough so that that can't occur. To be totally safe, make sure that `num` is <= than the length of the smallest sequence. With the given data, `num` is 100 and the smallest sequence is `vpop_items`, which contains 100 items, so we don't need to worry.

Thanks to Andras Deak for bringing this important point to my attention.

---

As I said earlier, there's bound to be a smarter way to do this: rather than calculating `counts` in a loop we *should* be able to just generate those counts directly using appropriate mathematics, but I'm afraid I don't know (or don't remember) how to do that. Of course, we *could* "cheat". :) Using the given data, we want approximately 50 items from `vpop_items`, 35 items from `pop_items` and the remaining 15 items from `reg_items`. So we could set `counts` to `[50, 35, 15]` and then make a small random adjustment to each count, taking care to keep the total equal to 100.

Comment: Hey thats a nice solution. I would add a guard to counts[i] not to get over the sample size. Just need to decide where to throw that sample

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward numpy solution that makes use of the fact that you only have three categories. This probably doesn't scale well for too many categories, as it just loops over the three choices.

First, generate uniform pseudorandoms to determine how many samples to take from which group. Then, use `numpy.random.choice` to perform the sampling:

```
import numpy as np

# data setup
N_ITEMS = 1000

items = list(range(0, N_ITEMS)) #python 3

vpop = int(len(items)*0.1)
pop = int(len(items)*0.3)

np.random.shuffle(items)
vpop_items = items[:vpop]
pop_items = items[vpop:pop]
reg_items = items[pop:]

# actual answer
def randsample(data1,data2,data3,probs,samples):
    # "samples" is the number of samples to take
    uniforms = np.random.rand(samples)
    inds1 = uniforms<=probs[0]
    inds2 = (probs[0]<uniforms) & (uniforms<=probs[0]+probs[1])
    inds3 = ~(inds1|inds2)

    output = np.empty(samples,dtype=type(data1[0])) #set dtype
    for ind,dat in zip((inds1,inds2,inds3),(data1,data2,data3)):
        output[ind] = np.random.choice(dat,ind.sum(),replace=False)

    #TODO: guard against depletion of one of the data sources...

    return output

res = randsample(vpop_items, pop_items, reg_items, [0.5, 0.35, 0.15], 100)
```

The array `uniforms` contains a pseudorandom uniform number between 0 and 1 for each sample point. We compare these numbers to the (cumulative) probabilities given in the input, in order to choose from the respective categories with the prescribed probability. Generally, for a given sample we choose from type `i` if the corresponding pseudorandom number is between `sum(probs[:i])` and `sum(probs[:i+1])`. The three index arrays `inds1,inds2,inds3` give a disjoint partitioning of our output samples, specifying the type of category for the given sample point. Then all we have to do is to set the corresponding indices of the output array based on a random choice from the given category.

Just to check that the resulting samples are correct and representative:

```
>>> np.in1d(res, vpop_items).sum()/res.size
0.53000000000000003
>>> np.in1d(res, pop_items).sum()/res.size
0.34000000000000002
>>> np.in1d(res, reg_items).sum()/res.size
0.13
>>> (np.in1d(res, reg_items) & np.in1d(res,pop_items)).sum()
0
>>> (np.in1d(res, reg_items) & np.in1d(res,vpop_items)).sum()
0
>>> (np.in1d(res, pop_items) & np.in1d(res,vpop_items)).sum()
0
```